# D3.js Dragging in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

after researching for almost 2 days I am still struggling with understanding how d3.js drag behavior in Angular/Typescript works. I´m using the D3 to Angular Service ([npm dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-ng2-service)) and pass data to the function in the snippet.

The circles are added and rendered perfectly, still there is absolutely no drag behaviour.

```
render(data: any[]): void {

    let d3 = this.d3;

    this.d3SVG
       .selectAll('circle')
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append('circle')
           .attr("cx", d => d.x)
           .attr("cy", d => d.y)
           .attr("r", this.radius)
           .attr("fill", 'red')
           .style("stroke", 'black')
           .on("mouseout", function (d) { // TODO})
           .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended)
  );

 function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}}
```

When clicking the circles following stacktrace is shown in Chrome:

```
Cannot read property 'ctrlKey' of null
    at SVGCircleElement.defaultFilter (drag.js:10)
    at SVGCircleElement.mousedowned (drag.js:51)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (on.js:27)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:431)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26919)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:430)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:198)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:513)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1671)
    at SVGCircleElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1697)
```

Can anybody explain this to me? I´m building an application with (hopefully) a lot of d3.js interaction and am really interested in understanding the behaviour.

**PS:** Are there good resources/best practice guidelines for building apps with d3.js and Angular/Typescript?

Comment: I'm also looking into this today. In my case the first argument of these drag event is supposed to be a DragEvent but it's always been undefined no matter if I use the fat arrow notation or the classic function() notation. Maybe things are different in your version of d3, but are you getting a DragEvent instance for "d"? Why are you assigning its x/y to itself?

Answer (score 0):

Component methods do not, by default, have their 'this' pointer bound.
A quick fix is to turn your exposed method into a "fat arrow function", which does have the 'this' pointer bound.

So, for example, change from

```
function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}
```

to

```
const dragstarted = (d) => {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the situation is the same after making the changes :/